# Story where a village used the people to assemble themselves into a large being to fight another village

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Where the people became the legs torso arms head and walked and battled a neighboring village.

Comment: Do you have any other information? When you read it, environment, future, past, anything?

Answer (score 9):

This is from Clive Barker's **Books of Blood**.
From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_Blood#In_the_Hills.2C_the_Cities):
**In the Hills, the Cities**

*Two gay men, Mick and Judd, take a romantic but strained vacation in Yugoslavia. In an isolated rural area, two entire cities, Popolac and Podujevo, create massive communal creatures by binding together the bodies of their citizens. Almost forty thousand people walk as the body of a single giant as tall as a skyscraper. This ritual occurs every ten years, but this time things go wrong and the Podujevo giant collapses, killing tens of thousands of citizens horribly. In shock, the entire population of Popolac goes mad and become the giant they are strapped into. Popolac wanders the hills aimlessly. By nightfall many of the people who make up the giant die from exhaustion, but the giant continues walking.*